# How much cash in INR can I bring to India

Tags: canada, india, cash

While traveling to India from Canada as a Canadian citizen, how much cold hard cash in INR am I allowed to bring to the country? I dont want to use credit card and pay FX conversion fee of 2.5%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are allowed to carry up to USD 5000 or equivalent without having to declare customs. There is no limit with declaration. Ofcourse if you walk with USD 1 million there would be quite a few questions. I would suggest you to not carry more than $1500- $2000 in cash as there can be a lot of crime in India and there is a slim chance that you get robbed. Also, the officers on duty are not sure about the limit as well, so if they see it, they will try and harass you.

Cheers,